# Display Image From browse button

Tags: c++, mfc

I am new to C++ and I'm using MFC by Visual Studio 2012
How can I display an Image in a picture control from browse button?
On browse button click, I set the path to an edit control like that

```
void CSimilarityOfImagesDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CFileDialog dlg(TRUE);
    int iRet = dlg.DoModal();
    CString path = dlg.GetPathName();

    SetWindowText (path);
    CEdit* cedit;
    cedit = reinterpret_cast<CEdit *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1));
    cedit->SetWindowTextW(path);
    cedit->GetWindowTextW(path);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MFC/ATL framework comes with `CImage` class that allows you to load images (PNG, JPEG, BMP, GIF and other formats are supported). In order to display the target image in your picture control you need to use the `CStatic::SetBitmap()` method. The `CImage` class implements `Detach()` method that allows you to get direct access to `HBITMAP` object. Here is an example:

The `m_PictureCtrl` is defined in your dialog window header file like this:

```
CStatic m_PictureCtrl;
```

It is mapped to `IDC_PIC_STATIC` control ID using standard **MFC Data Exchange** mechanism.

```
void CTestPicDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_PIC_STATIC, m_PictureCtrl);
}
```

The Browse Button handler looks like this:

```
CFileDialog dlg(TRUE);
if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{    
    CString sPath = dlg.GetPathName();

    CImage img;
    HRESULT hr = img.Load(sPath);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString sErrorMsg;
        sErrorMsg.Format(_T("Failed to load %s"), sPath );    
        AfxMessageBox(sErrorMsg);
        return;
    }

    CRect rect;
    m_PictureCtrl.GetClientRect(rect);
    int nWidth = rect.Width();
    int nHeight = rect.Height();

    CDC* pScreenDC = GetDC();
    CDC MemDC;
    MemDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pScreenDC);
    CBitmap bmp;
    bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pScreenDC, nWidth, nHeight);

    CBitmap *pOldObj = MemDC.SelectObject(&bmp);
    img.StretchBlt(MemDC.m_hDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, 0, 0, img.GetWidth(), img.GetHeight(), SRCCOPY);
    MemDC.SelectObject(pOldObj);

    m_PictureCtrl.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)bmp.Detach());
    ReleaseDC(pScreenDC);
}
```

Comment: sry but what is m_PictureCtrl? Is it the ID?

Comment: I've extended the answer to add m_PictureCtrl definition.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Another question where can I find the Do Data Exchange? I still searching for it

Comment: Open your dialog resource and select target control. Right click on it and hit Add Variable... Type your variable name, hit Finish and VS will create the rest for you.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin can you please tell me what is `IDC_PIC_STATIC` and how to create it. If I press `"Add variable"` on dialog I got error `Dialog has no controls`. Thnaks in advance